# android studio: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class java.awt.Point that attempts to sub-type erroneous class java.awt.geom.Point2D

Tags: java, android, class

I'm developing an app that modify a pdf (with pdfbox) after asking for some information to put in it and send it after per mail (javamail), I have this error since 1 week and I really don't find anything that can cause that

java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class java.awt.Point that attempts to sub-type erroneous class java.awt.geom.Point2D (declaration of 'java.awt.Point')

I'm a very beginner in android studio so it's probably something basic but I still can't find it

Don't know if it's the right part of my code but I'll show some:

The pdf creation:

```
        String original="/storage/sdcard/DCIM/original.pdf";

        File file = new File(original);
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);

        try {
            PDPage page;
            doc.removePage(2);
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
            page = doc.getPage(0);
            PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);

            contents.beginText();
            contents.setFont(font, 12);
            contents.newLineAtOffset(75, 700);
            contents.showText(MainActivity2.client);
            contents.endText();

            contents.beginText();
            contents.newLineAtOffset(215, 690);
            contents.showText(MainActivity2.projet);
            contents.endText(); 


            contents.close();
            doc.save(position);
        }
        finally {
            doc.close();
        }
```

the mail:

```
public void mail() throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("IDontPutItHere@gmail.fr"));

            envoie pdf=new envoie();
            pdf.pdf();
            message.setSubject("Bordereau chantier");
            File file = new File(pdf.position);
            FileDataSource datasource1 = new FileDataSource(file);
            DataHandler handler1 = new DataHandler(datasource1);
            MimeBodyPart bordereau = new MimeBodyPart();
            bordereau.setDataHandler(handler1);
            bordereau.setFileName(datasource1.getName());
            MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
            content.setContent("Ceci est un exemple de mail envoyé automatiquement avec un bordereau", "text/plain");
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(content);
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bordereau);
            message.setContent(mimeMultipart);


            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

New Edit: after some research it crash when it need to load the original file (File file = new File(original);
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);)

Comment: Hi Hactoris, welcome to SO. In answering any questions such as yours, we really do need to see some code, even if you've stated that you don't know what code to provide. Else it is extremely difficult for us volunteers to answer and as such, it probably will remain unanswered.

Comment: I'll try to edit and show a little of it so, dk if it will be the right part but better than nothing I guess